# python dataframe to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a dataframe into excel file, using `df.to_excel`. I've already done it with an older project before but now I have a dataframe which contains more than one value in some cases of the table.
For example there is a little part on my dataframe; we can see that the 2 last rows of `column2` countains two values :

```
----------column 1--------------column 2--------------

2016-08-05 20:57:58----[2016-08-05 21:03:24]   
2016-08-05 21:03:29----[2016-08-05 21:03:41]   
2016-08-05 21:04:27----[2016-08-06 02:03:11]   
2016-08-06 02:03:16----[2016-08-06 02:03:27, 2016-08-06 02:12:08]   
2016-08-06 02:12:53----[2016-08-06 02:13:04, 2016-08-06 02:13:12]
```

I want to know if it is possible to convert that kind of stuff into an excel file, because I tried but it seems like these multiple values prevent to do that convertion.
I thought about converting each value into strings and then concatenate them into a unique string, but if someone knows another easier way to answer this problem, I'm listening!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting merge_cells=True?

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html